# expected value for random number selection

Tags: expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Given x was randomly picked from $X={1,2, \cdots n}$ and that Y was randomly picked such that $Y<X$. I am interested in expected value of Y.

From my calculations:

$$ P(Y=j ) = \sum_{k} P(Y=j \mid k) P(X=k)  = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}  $$

$$ P(Y=j \mid X=j ) = \frac{P(X=j,Y=j)}{P(X=j)}= \frac{1}{j}  $$

For the expectation, I could do:
$$ E(Y) = \sum_{j=1}^n y_j P(Y=y_j) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}   $$

And also do:
$$E(Y\mid X) =  \sum_{k=1}^n y_k P(Y\mid X) =  \sum_{k=1}^n y_k \frac{1}{j}  $$
$$ E(E(Y\mid X)) = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j E(Y\mid X) =  \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \sum_{k=1}^n y_k \frac{1}{j} $$

I think simpler approach is:

$$E(Y\mid X) = \frac{(X+1)}{2}   $$
Since given $X$, $Y$ is uniform from $\{1,2 \cdots X\}$

$$ E(E(Y\mid X)) =E(\frac{X+1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}\left(E(X) +E(1) \right) =  \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{n+1}{2} +1\right)= \frac{n+3}{4} $$

Does this makes sense?

Comment: @JeanMarie that is a nice perspective and approach.

Comment: @JeanMarie does the update make sense?

Comment: Yes, this update is perfectly correct. I have simulated the experiment giving a very close agreement. Besides, I realize that my "continuous analogy" wasn't good. Therefore, I have erased it.

Comment: ... and I have replaced it by a correct one that I have posted below.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to establish a correspondence between this discrete question and its natural continuous "counterpart".

Consider that $X \approx Unif([0,1])$.

Saying that $Y$ is chosen in a uniform way in $[0,X]$ is equivalent to writing it as the product of 2 independent uniform random variables $X,Z \approx Unif([0,1]):$

$$Y=ZX$$

Consequently, due to independence:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(Z)\mathbb{E}(X)=(\tfrac12)^2=\tfrac14$$

Now, if instead of a $[0,1]$ range, one has a $[1,n]$ range, a natural discrete-to-continuous analogy gives, by proportionality, a mathematical expectation equivalent to $\frac{n}{4}$ (for large values of $n$) which is indeed the case for your result $\frac{n+3}{4}.$

**Remark** : This continuous reasoning could hopefuly be adapted into a proof of this question remaining in the discrete world...